# I cannot delete item from listview

Tags: java, android

I pass data from a listview to another listview with sharedpreferences. I can write items, I cannot remove an item of them. I dont have error but I have no result.

**MyActivity**

```
final DataProvider[] providers = gson.fromJson(jsonurun, DataProvider[].class);
final List<DataProvider> list = Arrays.asList(providers);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Listele1.this);
            builder.setMessage("Silinsin mi ?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("EVET", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            List<DataProvider> list1 = new ArrayList<DataProvider>(list);//list from 2nd line
                            list1.remove(dataProvider);
                            prefAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            prefAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        }
                    })
```

My custom adapter is **PrefAdapter**

```
List<DataProvider> list ;

public PrefAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<DataProvider> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.child_layout,list);
    this.list = list;
}

static class LayoutHandler{
    TextView ad,fiyat;
}

@Override
public void add(DataProvider dataProvider) {
    super.add(dataProvider);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void remove(DataProvider object) {
    super.remove(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create `list1`, or if you need it for whatever reason, you need to recreate the adapter with it

You should create the first list as this so you can remove from it

```
list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(providers)):
```

Comment: If I just write 'list.remove(dataProvider)' , I get 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' error message from this line

Answer (score 0):

You're never removing the item from the adapter. call remove on the adapter, and update the list in the adapter as well since you maintain a reference to it there.