# Delete item permanenly from ListView

Tags: android

I pass data from a `ListView` to another `ListView` with `SharedPreference`. I can write items and can remove an item of them.

After I delete item,I restart this page and I see item which I deleted. I cannot remove it permanently.

**MainActivity**

```
final DataProvider[] providers = gson.fromJson(jsonurun, DataProvider[].class);
final List<DataProvider> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(providers));

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        final DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Listele1.this);
        builder.setMessage("Silinsin mi ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("EVET", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        list.remove(dataProvider);
                        prefAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
            })
```

Comment: How you are setting the data to your adapter.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620005/i-cannot-delete-item-from-listview   in this link PrefAdapter

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
 prefAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

for `notifyItemRemoved("here, position you has deleted");
    notifyItemRangeChanged("here, position you has deleted" ,"your array".size());`

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing data form ListView 1 to ListView 2 using SharedPreference.
    using below 2 lines.

```
final DataProvider[] providers = gson.fromJson(jsonurun, DataProvider[].class);
final List<DataProvider> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(providers));

You only remove data from Listview 2 ie: list in your
case : list.remove(dataProvider);

And forgot to delete the data from SharedPreference at same time.That's why when restart the page your deleted item is visible again.


In short try to remove data form SharedPreference as well after performing

 list.remove(dataProvider);
 prefAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I cannot understand very well . Can you explain with sample code?